# How to add new column from another table based on a condition in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql

### Table A

```
Org ID  int not null

Org Name varchar
```

### Table B

```
AccountID int not null

OrgID  int not null
```

I want to add the `AccountID` column into `Table A` from `Table B` based on the condition

```
A.Org ID = B.Org.ID
```

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: have you tried this and seeing any issue? can you paste the code that you tried?

Comment: I am not sure which one to use like update set commands, merge, inner join ??

Comment: you need to use update with join

Comment: could u please advise the sample query based on the question above?

Comment: added the answer, you can build on top of this for next time you have to do such updates with joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.AccountID = B.AccountID
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
on A.OrgID = B.OrgID
```

Comment: I am getting the following error                                           Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'AccountID' in table 'dbo.Whitespace' is specified more than once.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "A.AccountID" could not be bound.

Comment: @Shiningstar, looks like you already have the accountid column, then just ry the upadate

Comment: Now I am getting following error    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "A.AccountID" could not be bound.

Comment: @Shiningstar, does the column AccountId exists ? have you tried adding it to correct table?

Comment: No..Table A doen't have [AccountID] column. @RADAR

Comment: @Shiningstar, you need to add it using alter command,     ALTER TABLE TableA add  AccountID int

Comment: I added a column [AccountID] which has NULL values now. and executed above query.It returned me this error...Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "A.AccountID" could not be bound.

Comment: @Shiningstar, it is simple update statement, did you alias name as A like what i have

Comment: Great ! YOU ARE RIGHT ! I didn't use alias here ! Thanks for patience. I would really appreciate it 1